# how to plot spectrogram of a specific window in time domain out of the spectrogram of all signal?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, spectrogram

I have produced spectrogram of a signal using matlab like this:

```
[S,F,T,P]=spectrogram(...);%I have used my desired parameters
```

and I have ploted the result :(the spectrogram of whole signal)

[image: the spectrogram of the whole signal]

my question is that now I want to plot a part of this spectrogram which stands for a specific window of my signal in time domain (say from sample number 900 - 920 in my signal vector).
And I want to know how to do it using the out put of the spectrogram function(the S, F , T , P).

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do it would be to use `xlim`:

```
xlim([1 1.5]);
```

to plot the [1 1.5] second window, or

```
xlim(T([900 920]));
```

if you prefer to specify indexes in your time vector.